# Action Constraint - Local Space With Parent NOT WORKING

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints, drivers, transform-orientation

I've created an action constraint for the shoulder when the hand controller moves in local space (with parent) in one direction. It works fine when the character is upright, but not when the character is rotated at all.

[image]

Upon rotation of any parent bone in the chain, the constraint is not evaluated the same. Even though the local transformation is exactly the same on the hand bone (which drives the action constraint). Example with root bone rotated 45 degrees:
[image]

Here's what the constraint setup looks like:
[image]

This problem happens whether I select "Local" or "Local with Parent" for the target transform type. Anyone have an idea what's going on here? It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Is it an Auto Rig Pro rig? If so be aware that it helds lots of inconstancies, expecially on constraints, baking animations and visual keying. I gave up all experiments on its cusomizations and switched back to good old solid Rigify.

Comment: I have had this problem on non-Auto-Rig-Pro rigs as well; but yes, this is a customized ARP rig. The constraint setup is very very simple, and the problem is reproduceable even on a simple 2-bone armature. So I think it's a bug. I've reported it here:
https://developer.blender.org/T95896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem only happens when a Child of Constraint is used on the bone driving the action constraint. When you use a bone with a true parent to drive the action constraint this behaves as expected.

It is a bug and being tracked here:
https://developer.blender.org/T95896